# javafx package javafx.embed.swt not in java8u5

Tags: jar, javafx, package

I'd like to use FXCanvas from the package javafx.embed.swt as shown in this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm# But all I can find is javafx.embed.swing package. javafx.embed.swt is simply not existant.   What am I doing wrong ? I use java8u5. Is there a special download nessessary or is there a different version of java that contains that package ??

thanks for any hint!
Thorsten

Answer (score 4):

This because the package `javafx.embed.swt` was moved from the `/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` to `/lib/jfxswt.jar`. You need to add this last explicitly to see the FXCanvas class.
This is the [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8102633) to the issue: **Separate javafx.embed.swt from jfxrt.jar**

Answer (score 2):

The JavaFX SWT embedding classes are in the `jre/lib` directory.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b14, mixed mode)

$ pwd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib

$ ls jfxswt.jar 
jfxswt.jar

$ jar tvf jfxswt.jar | grep FXCanvas.class
18702 Mon May 12 21:52:14 PDT 2014 javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.class
```

I've never used SWT in JavaFX so I don't really know anything about how to use it.  If you would like more assistance, post to the [e(fx)clipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) for advice - they are experts on such matters.

Also refer to the version of the documentation which matches the version of Java you are using:

- [8 JavaFX Interoperability with SWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx-swt_interoperability.htm).