# Maven javafx with java 8

Tags: maven, javafx

After fixing some problems with maven I am having some with my standalone app, all my other libraries seem to load properly.
I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas
        at mapper.osm.main.Main.createContents(Main.java:280)
        at mapper.osm.main.Main.open(Main.java:182)
        at mapper.osm.main.Main.main(Main.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more

jdc@hal-win MINGW64 ~/git/mapper-osm/mapper.osm/target (master)
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

I added this plugin to my pom.xml, but I still get the same problem https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin.

Isnt java 8 supposed to run with javafx natively?

Comment: `javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas` is a class from the the [JavaFX SWT compability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx-swt_interoperability.htm). It's not in the JDK directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tycho then this should solve your issue http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/05/15/maven-tycho-0-20-0-and-java8-source-code/

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, it cannot find a class, named FXCanvas under javafx/embed/swt. You need to add `jfxswt.jar` to your class path. There are two links, which may help you solve your issue. [link 1](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/add-javafx-controls-swt-eclipse-4-application-eclipse-rcp-cookbook/)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841798/javafx-package-javafx-embed-swt-not-in-java8u5)

I hope this helps.